# gulp-imagemin - how to disregard directory structures?

Tags: javascript, gulp, imagemin, gulp-imagemin

I'm using `gulp-imagemin` in it's basic form

```
gulp.task('image', function() {

  return gulp.src('./images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        use: [pngquant()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));

});
```

My `images/` directory looks like

```
 images/
   logo.png

   subfolder/
     image.png
```

I would like them to output as such:

```
 build/
   logo.png
   image.png
```

But they are retaining their folder structure.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) by adding `.pipe(flatten())` after the `.imagemin()`