# Using gulp-image or Gulp-imagemin with multiple subdirectories

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I am using [Gulp-image plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image) atm (Also tried gulp-imagemin).

## My gulpfile.js markup:

```
// Include gulp
const gulp = require('gulp')

// Include gulp plugins
const images = require('gulp-image')

// Image optimalization
gulp.task('images', () => {
  gulp.src('uploads/**/*')
  .pipe(images())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./Compressed-images/'));
})

gulp.task('default', ['images'])
```

Now this is where it goes wrong:

```
gulp.src('uploads/**/*')
```

It only takes all images from the subdirectories in the directory:

```
uploads/
```

Is there any way to access the images for multiple levels of directories without having to type them all out?

## For example:

Accesing images in the directory:

```
uploads/sub-dir-1/sub-dir-3/sub-dir-3/
```

Without having to typ something like this?

```
uploads/sub-dir-1/sub-dir-2/sub-dir-3/*.jpg
uploads/**/**/**/*.jpg
```

#### I read the following posts

- [Gulp rename all images based on other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726388/gulp-rename-all-images-based-on-other-directory)
- [gulp-imagemin - how to disregard directory structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712566/gulp-imagemin-how-to-disregard-directory-structures)
- [Replicating directory structure in Gulp dest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015384/replicating-directory-structure-in-gulp-dest)

But couldn't find an answer there.

Comment: `uploads/**/*` **does** match multiple subdirectories -> [glob primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer)

Comment: Yes it will match all directories inside the uploads/ directory but it will not match any directory inside the subdirectories..

Comment: No, you're wrong. It **does** match directories inside the subdirectories.

Comment: when I run the code above this is what happends - it creates sub-dir-1/ with all the images from that directory inside the Compressed-images/ and it will also create the sub-dir-2/ directory but that directory will be empty...

Comment: Tried it. `sub-dir-2` is not empty, just as I said. You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also read the link to the glob primer I posted. It mentions symlinks. Make sure this isn't the problem. [`gulp-debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) might also help.

Comment: Nvm it seemed like it just couldn't handle the amount of images I had in diffrent directories...  I tried it with 1 or 2 images in a few directories and it worked as expected, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work. I did a couple of tests and it works fine for me, I added 3 levels and it worked. Here's the output

```
[23:08:34] ✔ test.png -> before=69.25 KB after=20.1 KB reduced=49.15 KB(71%)
[23:08:34] ✔ sub1/sub2/ub3/test.png -> before=69.25 KB after=20.1 KB reduced=49.15 KB(71%)
[23:08:34] ✔ sub1/sub2/test.png -> before=69.25 KB after=20.1 KB reduced=49.15 KB(71%)
[23:08:34] ✔ sub1/test.png -> before=69.25 KB after=20.1 KB reduced=49.15 KB(71%)
```

You can also try to use [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to see what files you're grabbing.

I'm more inclined to think that something is failing silently when the images are compressing, maybe an image is corrupt.